# Rearrange pfSense interface order

Tags: pfsense

I want to organize a pfSense firewall that I got already running and the first thing is the interface order.

I know that pfSense is a little bit harsh when coming to rearrange things, but I would like to know if there's any easy way to reorder the interfaces on the Firewall, here's the status today:

[image: pfSense Interfaces]

In this case I want to put the WAN interfaces on top, followed by PFSYNC, MGMT, SRV and finally LAN.

This is just for organisation, but pfSense does not appears to support, at least on the web interface, any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pfSense allows you to sort the interfaces in two ways.

1. The default order, which is WAN, LAN, and then all remaining interfaces in the order they were created.
2. Alphabetical.

The simplest thing to do is to add numbers to your interface names:

- 1_WAN1
- 1_WAN2
- 2_PFSYNC
- 3_MGMT
- 4_SRV
- 5_LAN

Then go to "System" -> "General Settings", find "Interfaces Sort" about halfway down the page, check the box for "Sort Alphabetically", and click "Save" at the bottom.

(Note: Yes, both WANs are prefixed with `1`. They will sort properly anyway, and there's no reason to use extra numbers since all that will do is increase the likelihood of needing to renumber if a third WAN is added later.)

Comment: Although it does not really solves the issue this can be a good workaround. If someone came with anything better I will accept. Thanks!

Comment: What if reorder them manually in XML file?

Comment: @SergeyKostrukov - Did u every try that ? Worked ?

Comment: @MarcoZen he's probably lost his internet connection since then. :)

Comment: @Vame - Hehehe. Anyway, I tried this method and it worked.